# I'm using a ChangeNotifierProvider with a showModalBottomSheet and experiencing lag

Tags: flutter

When I first show the modal sheet, there's a lag in the animation slightly compared to when I don't use the ChangeNotifierProvider. Here's my code

```
\`class SchedulePage extends StatefulWidget {
const SchedulePage({super.key, required this.userProfile});
final PersonalProfile userProfile;

@override
State\<SchedulePage\> createState() =\> \_SchedulePage();
}

class \_SchedulePage extends State\<SchedulePage\> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ChangeNotifierProvider(
create: (context) =\> MyModel(),
builder: (context, child) {
return Center(
child: SingleChildScrollView(
child: Column(
children: \[
Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
children: \[
const Flexible(
child: Text(
'Work Schedule',
textScaleFactor: 1.5,
),
),
GestureDetector(
onTap: () {
print('tapped');
createModalSheet(context, widget.userProfile);
},
child: Container(
margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
child: const Icon(Icons.today)),
)
\],
),
\],
),
),
);
});
}
}

Future\<void\> createModalSheet(
BuildContext context, PersonalProfile userProfile) {
final myModel = Provider.of\<MyModel\>(context, listen: false);

return showModalBottomSheet\<void\>(
useRootNavigator: true,
backgroundColor: Colors.white,
isScrollControlled: true,
shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20))),
context: context,
builder: (BuildContext context) {
return ListenableProvider.value(
value: myModel,
child: RealWidget(
userProfile: userProfile,
),
);
// return ChangeNotifierTest(
//   userProfile: userProfile,
// );
});
}

class RealWidget extends StatelessWidget {
RealWidget({
super.key,
required this.userProfile,
});
PersonalProfile userProfile;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Column(
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
children: \[
Container(
decoration: const BoxDecoration(),
padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 0, 16, 0),
height: getScreenHeight(context, heightMultiplier: 2.0 / 3.0),
child: ScheduleList(userProfile: userProfile),
),
const ModalSheetEditBar(),
\],
);
}
}

class ChangeNotifierTest extends StatelessWidget {
const ChangeNotifierTest({
super.key,
required this.userProfile,
});

final PersonalProfile userProfile;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ChangeNotifierProvider(
create: (context) {
return MyModel();
},
builder: (context, child) {
return Column(
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
children: \[
Container(
decoration: const BoxDecoration(),
padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 0, 16, 0),
height: getScreenHeight(context, heightMultiplier: 2.0 / 3.0),
child: child,
),
const ModalSheetEditBar(),
\],
);
},
child: ScheduleList(userProfile: userProfile),
);
}
}

class ModalSheetEditBar extends StatelessWidget {
const ModalSheetEditBar({
super.key,
});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final myModel = context.watch\<MyModel\>();

    return Container(
        height: getScreenHeight(context, heightMultiplier: .08),
        width: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.amber,
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    print('Add Schedule Tapped');
                  },
                  child: Text('Add Schedule')),
              GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    print('Edit Tapped');
                    myModel.increment;
                  },
                  child: Text('Edit')),
            ],
          ),
        ));

}
}

class ScheduleList extends StatelessWidget {
const ScheduleList({
super.key,
required this.userProfile,
});

// This should be scheduleList in the profile eventually
final PersonalProfile userProfile;

Widget scheduleRow(int index) {
final List\<String\> items = userProfile.getScheduleList();
Widget scheduleRowInfo = Card(
color: Colors.green,
shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
child: ListTile(
title: Text(items\[index\]),
trailing: Visibility(
visible: index == userProfile.getSelectedScheduleIndex(),
child: const Icon(Icons.check)),
),
);

    if (items.length == 1) {
      return ReusableListItem(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), child: scheduleRowInfo);
    }
    
    // Border is different for the first and last item if there are >= 2 items.
    if (index == 0) {
      return ReusableListItem(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(10)),
          child: scheduleRowInfo);
    } else if (index == items.length - 1) {
      return ReusableListItem(
          borderRadius:
              const BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(10)),
          topBorder: const BorderSide(width: 0),
          child: scheduleRowInfo);
    }
    return ReusableListItem(
        topBorder: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 0),
        child: scheduleRowInfo);

}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final List\<String\> items = userProfile.getScheduleList();

    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            const Text('Placeholder Modal BottomSheet'),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: items.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return scheduleRow(index);
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );

}
}

class MyModel extends ChangeNotifier {
int \_count = 0;
int get count =\> \_count;

void increment() {
\_count += 1;
notifyListeners();
}
}

class ReusableListItem extends StatelessWidget {
const ReusableListItem({
super.key,
this.leftBorder = const BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
this.topBorder = const BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
this.rightBorder = const BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
this.bottomBorder = const BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
this.borderRadius = const BorderRadius.all(Radius.zero),
required this.child,
});

final BorderSide leftBorder;
final BorderSide topBorder;
final BorderSide rightBorder;
final BorderSide bottomBorder;
final BorderRadius borderRadius;
final Widget child;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
decoration: BoxDecoration(
borderRadius: borderRadius,
border: Border(
left: leftBorder,
top: topBorder,
right: rightBorder,
bottom: bottomBorder,
)),
child: child,
);
}
}\`
```

and this is the code without the provider

```
\`class SchedulePage extends StatefulWidget {
const SchedulePage({super.key, required this.userProfile});
final PersonalProfile userProfile;

@override
State\<SchedulePage\> createState() =\> \_SchedulePage();
}

class \_SchedulePage extends State\<SchedulePage\> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Center(
child: SingleChildScrollView(
child: Column(
children: \[
Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
children: \[
const Flexible(
child: Text(
'Work Schedule',
textScaleFactor: 1.5,
),
),
GestureDetector(
onTap: () {
print('tapped');
createModalSheet(context, widget.userProfile);
},
child: Container(
margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
child: const Icon(Icons.today)),
)
\],
),
\],
),
),
);
}
}

Future\<void\> createModalSheet(
BuildContext context, PersonalProfile userProfile) {
// final myModel = Provider.of\<MyModel\>(context, listen: false);

return showModalBottomSheet\<void\>(
useRootNavigator: true,
backgroundColor: Colors.white,
isScrollControlled: true,
shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20))),
context: context,
builder: (BuildContext context) {
return RealWidget(
userProfile: userProfile,
);
// return ListenableProvider.value(
//   value: myModel,
//   child: RealWidget(
//     userProfile: userProfile,
//   ),
// );
// return ChangeNotifierTest(
//   userProfile: userProfile,
// );
});
}

class RealWidget extends StatelessWidget {
RealWidget({
super.key,
required this.userProfile,
});
PersonalProfile userProfile;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Column(
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
children: \[
Container(
decoration: const BoxDecoration(),
padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 0, 16, 0),
height: getScreenHeight(context, heightMultiplier: 2.0 / 3.0),
child: ScheduleList(userProfile: userProfile),
),
const ModalSheetEditBar(),
\],
);
}
}

class ChangeNotifierTest extends StatelessWidget {
const ChangeNotifierTest({
super.key,
required this.userProfile,
});

final PersonalProfile userProfile;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ChangeNotifierProvider(
create: (context) {
return MyModel();
},
builder: (context, child) {
return Column(
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
children: \[
Container(
decoration: const BoxDecoration(),
padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 0, 16, 0),
height: getScreenHeight(context, heightMultiplier: 2.0 / 3.0),
child: child,
),
const ModalSheetEditBar(),
\],
);
},
child: ScheduleList(userProfile: userProfile),
);
}
}

class ModalSheetEditBar extends StatelessWidget {
const ModalSheetEditBar({
super.key,
});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// final myModel = context.watch\<MyModel\>();

    return Container(
        height: getScreenHeight(context, heightMultiplier: .08),
        width: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.amber,
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    print('Add Schedule Tapped');
                  },
                  child: Text('Add Schedule')),
              GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    print('Edit Tapped');
                    // myModel.increment;
                  },
                  child: Text('Edit')),
            ],
          ),
        ));

}
}

class ScheduleList extends StatelessWidget {
const ScheduleList({
super.key,
required this.userProfile,
});

// This should be scheduleList in the profile eventually
final PersonalProfile userProfile;

Widget scheduleRow(int index) {
final List\<String\> items = userProfile.getScheduleList();
Widget scheduleRowInfo = Card(
color: Colors.green,
shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
child: ListTile(
title: Text(items\[index\]),
trailing: Visibility(
visible: index == userProfile.getSelectedScheduleIndex(),
child: const Icon(Icons.check)),
),
);

    if (items.length == 1) {
      return ReusableListItem(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), child: scheduleRowInfo);
    }
    
    // Border is different for the first and last item if there are >= 2 items.
    if (index == 0) {
      return ReusableListItem(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(10)),
          child: scheduleRowInfo);
    } else if (index == items.length - 1) {
      return ReusableListItem(
          borderRadius:
              const BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(10)),
          topBorder: const BorderSide(width: 0),
          child: scheduleRowInfo);
    }
    return ReusableListItem(
        topBorder: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 0),
        child: scheduleRowInfo);

}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final List\<String\> items = userProfile.getScheduleList();

    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            const Text('Placeholder Modal BottomSheet'),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: items.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return scheduleRow(index);
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );

}
}

class MyModel extends ChangeNotifier {
int \_count = 0;
int get count =\> \_count;

void increment() {
\_count += 1;
notifyListeners();
}
}

class ReusableListItem extends StatelessWidget {
const ReusableListItem({
super.key,
this.leftBorder = const BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
this.topBorder = const BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
this.rightBorder = const BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
this.bottomBorder = const BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0),
this.borderRadius = const BorderRadius.all(Radius.zero),
required this.child,
});

final BorderSide leftBorder;
final BorderSide topBorder;
final BorderSide rightBorder;
final BorderSide bottomBorder;
final BorderRadius borderRadius;
final Widget child;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
decoration: BoxDecoration(
borderRadius: borderRadius,
border: Border(
left: leftBorder,
top: topBorder,
right: rightBorder,
bottom: bottomBorder,
)),
child: child,
);
}
}\
```

I was trying to listen to changes made from a button pressed and it's causing a lag in animation. I don't know why. It would be nice if the animation was quicker but I don't get why it would be slower. Is there a better way to do this? Is there a way to make the animation faster?